# Use if statement against the ones place decimal value in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, floor, ceil

I need help creating a formula that rounds a number with a 1 or 6 in the ones place down to the nearest multiple of 5 (e.g., 276 to 275 or 131 to 130) and rounds any other number up to the nearest multiple of 5 (e.g., 277 to 280 or 132 to 135). I figured the logic would look something like this:

=if(can't figure out this condition, ceiling(A1,5), floor(A1,5))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MROUND` instead:

```
=MROUND(A1,5)
```

It rounds to the nearest 5. Anything including and above 277.5 will be rounded to 280, and anything below that will be rounded to 275.

If you still want to use `IF`, then I would pick `MOD`:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,5)>2.5, CEILING(A1,5), FLOOR(A1,5))
```

So, if the remainder is above 2.5 when divided by 5, round up, otherwise, down.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,1)="1",RIGHT(A1,1)="6"),FLOOR(A1,5),CEILING(A1,5)))
```

or little bit shorter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"16")),FLOOR(A1,5),CEILING(A1,5))
```